# vue js 2: Access props in mounted function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have data props in child components. Inside child component on mounted function I need to get specific value from props and set select dropdown value. I am using vue-multiselect plugin which is working fine. Here is the code.

```
module.exports = {
    props: ["Subscriptions"]
    mounted: function () {
        let vm = this;      


        Vue.nextTick(function () {      
        // I want to access props here but it return 0 length array 
            console.log(vm.$parent.Subscriptions);
        });
    },  
    beforeUpdate() {
        let vm = this;
        console.log(vm.$parent.Subscriptions);
    },
//  updated() {
//      let vm = this;
//      console.log(vm.$parent.Subscriptions);
//  }
};
```

Now only time I do get subscriptions is in beforeUpdate and updated function but this called each time there is a change in value which is not required. I only need to change it first time in order to set drop down initial value.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A common mistake could be, parent component pass a variable as a prop which is null at the moment where child component get rendered. Thus when you access it in mounted in child component. You see it as a null value. And at a later time, in Parent component the variable which was passed (prop) will be assign the values from an asynchronous operation. To avoid possible pitfalls, better to use v-if.

Example :

```
<ChildComponent :data="testData" />
```

instead of above below can be used

```
<ChildComponent v-if="testData" :data="testData" />
```

so that only when testData available child component will be rendered. But if in child component you have some more things to show until data comes in better to use another component. And adding watchers will also resolve the problem but not in a pretty way.

Since you get values in updated hook probably this could be the case.

Comment: From my opinion this is the best answer for this issue.

Comment: I have a simple String value in the prop. How is it possible it is not available in mounted hook?

Comment: Well, this answer's just saved me an hour or two, probably. And I've been using Vue for years.

Answer (score 18):

Why are you trying to access current component props through '$parent'?

It should work like this:

```
 module.exports = {
  props: ["Subscriptions"],
  mounted: function () {
      let vm = this;

      Vue.nextTick(function () {
        console.log(vm.Subscriptions);
      });
  },  
  beforeUpdate() {
    console.log(this.Subscriptions);
  },
  updated() {
    console.log(this.Subscriptions);
  }
};
```

**Update:**

Anyway, I don't know if you need next tick, try to use **created** function 
 and without nextTick.

```
created() {
  alert(this.Subscriptions);
},
```

Comment: OK I know that but problem this doesn't matter how i access it I simply get 0 based array inside mounted function.

Comment: Please show me how did you sent the props to this object

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your statement.

Comment: I did try created but that doesn't work either. It simply shows empty array. But in my view I am using Subscription data as a drop down list and it is populating alright. But I can't access it inside function.

Comment: could you please create a fiddle, it will be easier to see what is actually happening.

Comment: If your problem is about loading, `nextTick` is the correct answer which also worked for me. If not, you have to create a fiddle indeed to investigate further what the interaction is with parent

Comment: Put it on created() and it will work fine. thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 7):

Receive data from props:

```
module.exports = {
    props: ["Subscriptions"]
    mounted: function () {
        let vm = this;      

        vm.$nextTick(function () {      
           console.log(vm.Subscriptions);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 7):

I resolved a similar issue using @watch. Maybe this could work?

```
module.exports = {
  props: ["Subscriptions"]

  // this mounted is probably not necessary
  mounted: function () {
    getSubscriptions(this.Subscriptions)
  },  

  watch: {
    Subscriptions: [{
      handler: 'getSubscriptions'
    }]
  },

  methods: {
    getSubscriptions(el) {
      console.log(el);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by not using props at all. I instead fired a method  on the child component from the parent component, passing in an argument.

This can be done by setting a ref attribute on the child component element in  the parent component's template , then using this.$refs to access the method from any hook or method.

```html
<template>
<child-component ref="name"/>
</template>

<script>
export default{
mounted(){
this.$refs.name.methodName(data);
}
</script>
```

This can help in various situations - passing data and/or firing a method when something happens, and the reverse can also be done using this.$parent from the child component.

Answer (score 0):

##### setTimeout is a game changer here

it should work.

```js
mounted() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.getSubscriptions()
  }, 500);
},

methods: {
  getSubscriptions() {
     console.log(this.Subscriptions);
  }
}
```