# Vue js shows the props for just once from axios

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

I have component that get data from api and I pass this to another componet using props.
The proplem is when I `console.log(data)` It shows for first time and if I refresh the page or route to another page the `console.log(data)` shows empty, and I should make change in the code in order to shows the data in console

the component of getting data (main)

```
<template>
        <Video :videoSrc="videoSrc" />
</template>

import Video from './Ho'
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    name: 'VideoView',
    components: {
        Video
    },
    data(){
       return{
         videoSrc: '',
       }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getVideo()
    },
    methods: {
      async getVideo(){
          const videoID = this.$route.params.video_id
          await axios.get(`/video/api/video/${videoID}/`)
          .then(response => {
               this.videoSrc = response.data.video
          })
      }
    },
}
```

The child component

```
<script>
import VideoPlayer from '@/components/video/VideoPlayer.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Ho',
  components: {
    VideoPlayer
  },
  props: ['videoSrc'],
    
  },
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.vidSrc)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be     console.log(this.videoSrc) instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After did some search I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273525/vue-js-2-access-props-in-mounted-function) answer. I solved this propble by add `v-if` in chile component like this `<Video v-if="videoSrc" :videoSrc="videoSrc" />` and this solved my problem